# Ideal Profits in companies in Perfect Binary Search tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, dynamic-programming, memoization

I'm trying to solve the following problems here:

> In the X world, companies have a hierarchical structure to form a large binary tree network (can be assumed to be a perfect binary tree). Thus every company has two sub companies as their children with the root as company X. The total number of companies in the structure is N. The wealth of each company follow the same general trend and doubles after every month. Also after every year, half of the wealth is distributed to the two child companies (i.e. one fourth to each) if they exist (i.e. the leaf node companies do not distribute their wealth). Given the initial wealth of each of the N companies, you want to determine the final wealth of each company after m months.
> (A perfect binary tree is a special tree such that all leaf nodes are at the maximum depth of the tree, and the tree is completely filled with no gaps.)

> (a) Design an algorithm in `O(n^3 log(m))` complexity to find the final wealth of each company after m months.

To achieve the above mentioned constraints, I'm thinking it'll be great idea to introduce dynamic programming with memoisation.

The `dp` array would be of three dimensions `N*m*2` with `dp[i][j][k]` representing the wealth of company i after j months with k denoting whether the wealth has been distributed in the last year.

In the recursive step, I think while traversing the tree from the leaf to the root, and for every non-leaf node, calculate its wealth after `j` months using its children's wealth values from the previous month. This involves considering two cases: wealth distribution and wealth doubling.

a. If the wealth was not distributed in the last year (k = 0), calculate the wealth as the sum of the children's wealth `(dp[i][j-1][0] + dp[i][j-1][1])`
b. If the wealth was distributed in the last year (k = 1), calculate the wealth as half of the sum of the children's wealth `((dp[i][j-1][0] + dp[i][j-1][1]) / 2)`

Pseudocode for the same:

```
function calculateFinalWealth(initial_wealth[], m):
    N = length(initial_wealth)
    Initialize dp[N][m+1][2] array
    
    for i = 0 to N-1:
        dp[i][0][0] = initial_wealth[i]
    
    for j = 1 to m:
        for i = 0 to N-1:
            if i is a non-leaf node:
                dp[i][j][0] = dp[i][j-1][0] * 2
                dp[i][j][1] = (dp[i][j-1][0] + dp[i][j-1][1]) / 2
    
    return dp
```

> (b) Analyze the time complexity of your algorithm and briefly argue about the correctness of your solution.

I need help about how to discuss the correctness argument in this case apart from what I've already discussed above.

> (c) Consider the case of a single company (i.e. only root) in the tree. Give a constant time solution to find the final wealth after m months.

Since it is said the wealth of the company doubles after every `m` months, I think it should be safe to assume Final_Wealth = Initial_Wealth * 2^m

I just need to verify that this is indeed what I'm thinking.

Comment: You probably could use Math to get the expected value faster; probably not what they want with that run-time.

Answer (score -1):

#### Your algorithm:

First of all, the algorithm you describe has a complexity of O(m * n): you iterate once over all the months(m) and then once through all the companies(n). At every step, you do two operacions(C). O(m * n * C) = O(m * n).
You could argue that m * n is better than n^3 * log(m) and I tend to agree with the evaluation. However for some cases, such as reasonably small n and large m, it might not be the case. Also, it's not the question you're trying to answer.

Second of all, the algorithm you provide the pseudocode for doesn't work. The task you describe states:

> The wealth of each company follow the same general trend and doubles after every month. Also after every year, half of the wealth is distributed to the two child companies (i.e. one fourth to each) if they exist

yet your code:

```
if i is a non-leaf node:
                dp[i][j][0] = dp[i][j-1][0] * 2
                dp[i][j][1] = (dp[i][j-1][0] + dp[i][j-1][1]) / 2
```

has several issues:

- first, you only ever compute the wealth of non-leaf nodes. Given a perfect binary tree that we're to assume, that means that you downright ignore half of all existing companies(due to the fact that perfect binary tree has the same number of companies in the last row as in is in the rest of the tree). This is easily fixable though.
- second, you missed the fact, that you only ever distribute the wealth once every year. E.g. every 12 months. The way you do it is every year.
- lastly, I think that you array structure is weird and you in fact don't have a binary tree representation. Rather, you have two-dimensional array with 2N * (m + 1) nodes in total which is weird and likely doesn't work. So your algorithm most likely doesn't work at all. You either want a proper tree representation with nodes and children (a bit difficult to traverse) or a single array of N nodes and computing indices, where for company I, its children are nodes (2 * I) and (2 * I + 1) - look up for example array representation of binary heap to get a closer look.

#### Getting to solve this issue.

Let's start with the root company. What does the root company(R) do?

- Every month, it doubles its wealth: W(R) = W(R) * 2
- Every year, it gives away half of it's wealth: W(R) = W(R) / 2

Every other company, does the same, except once every year it also receives 1/4 of it's parents wealth.

So for every year, the company's wealth is:
**W(I) = W(I) * 2^11 + W(Parent) * 2^10**

 Now I don't know whether or not does the wealth distribution go bottom-up or top-down. E.g. how many layers to the bottom does the wealth trickle down. If only one(e.g. first you compute child nodes, then their parents, grandparents etc) or if the wealth from the root company trickles down the whole pyramid, diluting in the process. Your question doesn't make this clear for me.
The last year is an exception if the **m mod 12 != 0**, in that case there is no downwards distribution.
For a leaf company, there is small difference in **W(I) = W(I) * 2^12 + W(Parent) * 2^10** since there is no child to distribute half of wealth to.

Now the tricky part is getting to log(m). If there is only one company, this would be simple(not to mention that O(1) solution is possible), simply double the number of processed months at every step. **W(c)(m * 2) = W(C)(m)^2**

However the trickle down mechanics does pose a challenge, I think I'm beginning to see the n^3 mentioned in the solution. I've got to run now, I will get to this later if/when I have the time.

Comment: It'll be great if you can give the entire pseudocode/algorithm